# Can we use cookies for state management in a nodejs express application?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, express-session

I am developing a back end for a e-commerce website as a project for my university. I am not using any front end frameworks such as angular or react. So I have do the state management part myself. For example if a user adds an item to a shopping cart and goes to another page and comes back, the item should be there in the shopping cart. Can I implement this using cookies and sessions ? Can I enter data to a cookie from the front end ? (Here the front end means the views stored in the server and rendered using a template engine)

Comment: You can use cookies for that. You can make use of `localStorage` as well. But, I don't see why session is related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On front-end if you need to manage state of website/web applicaiton you better use redux or any similiar library. In cookies (adn localStorage) you limited with how much info you can store, and better leave it for authentication info.

If you need to save data between page reloading/user logout, then better make call to backend to save this item id to some in-cart collection or field.